# OpenGL ES 2.x: How to Discard Depth Buffer glDiscardFramebufferEXT?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, framebuffer, depth-buffer

I read [iOS OpenGL ES Logical Buffer Loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470822/ios-opengl-es-logical-buffer-loads) that a performance gain can be reached by "discarding" your depth buffer after each draw cycle.  I try this, but it's as my game engine is not rendering any longer.  I am getting an glError 1286, or GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION_EXT, when I try to render the next cycle.

I get the feeling I need to initialize or setup the depth buffer each cycle if I'm going to discard it, but I can't seem to find any information on this.  Here is how I init the depth buffer (all buffers, actually):

```
    // ---- GENERAL INIT ---- //        
    // Extract width and height.
    int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                                 GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &bufferWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                                 GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &bufferHeight);

    // Create a depth buffer that has the same size as the color buffer.
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_depthRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES, GAMESTATE->GetViewportSize().x, GAMESTATE->GetViewportSize().y);

    // Create the framebuffer object.
    GLuint framebuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                              GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_colorRenderbuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                              GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_colorRenderbuffer);
```

And here is what I'm trying to do to discard the depth buffer at the end of each draw cycle:

```
    // Discard the depth buffer
    const GLenum discards[]  = {GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_depthRenderbuffer);
    glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,1,discards);
```

I call that immediately following all of my draw calls and...

```
[m_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Any ideas?  Any info someone could point me to?  I tried reading through Apple's guide on the subject (where I got the original idea), http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html, but it doesn't seem to work quite right for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your call to `glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,1,discards)` is saying that you are discarding just 1 framebuffer attachment, however your discards array includes two: `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` and `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`.

Try changing it to:

```
glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 2, discards);
```

In fact, you say that you are discarding these framebuffer attachments at the end of the draw cycle, but directly before `[m_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];`. You are discarding the colour renderbuffer attachment that you need in order to present the renderbuffer - perhaps try just discarding the depth attachment, as this is no longer needed at this point.

You only need to initialise your buffers once, **not** every draw cycle. The `glDiscardFramebufferEXT()` doesn't actually delete your framebuffer attachment - it is simply a hint to the API to say that the contents of the renderbuffer are not needed in that draw cycle after the discard command completes. From Apple's [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW1):

> A discard operation is defined by the EXT_discard_framebuffer
>   extension and is available on iOS 4.0 and later. Discard operations
>   should be omitted when your application is running on earlier versions
>   of ioS, but included whenever they are available. A discard is a
>   performance hint to OpenGL ES; it tells OpenGL ES that the contents of
>   one or more renderbuffers are not used by your application after the
>   discard command completes. By hinting to OpenGL ES that your
>   application does not need the contents of a renderbuffer, the data in
>   the buffers can be discarded or expensive tasks to keep the contents
>   of those buffers updated can be avoided.

Comment: StuDev, you're right on the money - I was sending it 1 instead of 2 for the second argument.  Moreover, I was running the discard on GL_FRAMEBUFFER, though I was binding the depth buffer to GL_RENDERBUFFER when I instantiate it (that did the trick).

Comment: Interesting correction...  for me, I have to bind the depth buffer to the GL_RENDERBUFFER, but use the GL_FRAMEBUFFER enumerant when discarding.